# Trouble transforming a dataframe (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame. I want to transform it in way where it is ordered by "Days Left". IDs can be used more than once, and all Report numbers are unique. But I want every ID to appear once, before an already used ID is used again.

Like, AABBCC -> ABCABC or  AABCCC -> ABCACC.

How would I turn this.

| ID | Report | Days Left |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 171 | 11 | 5 |
| 171 | 12 | 9 |
| 182 | 13 | 1 |
| 182 | 14 | 2 |

into this?

| ID | Report | Days Left |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 182 | 13 | 1 |
| 171 | 11 | 5 |
| 182 | 14 | 2 |
| 171 | 12 | 9 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) should work

```py
df.sort_values("Days Left") \
  .assign(order=lambda x: x.groupby("ID").cumcount()) \
  .sort_values(["order", "Days Left"]) \
  .drop(columns="order")
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the solution

```
ID=[171,171,182,182]
Report=[11,12,13,14]
DaysLeft=[5,9,1,2]

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':ID,'report':Report,'daysleft':DaysLeft})
df=df.sort_values(by="daysleft",ascending=True)\
.assign(order=lambda x: x.groupby("id").cumcount())\
.sort_values(by=['order','daysleft'])

output:
    id  report  daysleft  order
2  182      13         1      0
0  171      11         5      0
3  182      14         2      1
1  171      12         9      1
```